# Maintain Windows File Shares When Logged Out

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

I have a Windows 2003 Server that connects to several Windows File Shares on other machines. I copy files to these file shares using some Scheduled Tasks that call a batch script. My issue is when the machine is logged out, the file shares are not there and the copies fail.

How can I maintain my file share connections regardless of whether my machine is logged in or not?

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a drive letter, use a UNC path, so if `Z:\` is `\\server\shares` then just have your batch copy to `\\server\shares\folder` instead of `Z:\folder`.